# Error in Laravel-mix

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, webpack, laravel-mix

I install Laravel-mix with npm and node on VPS

OS is Ubuntu 16.4

Laravel version is: 5.6

npm version is : 3.5.2

node version is: v4.2.6

After run `sudo npm run production`

show this error:

```
production /var/www/html
cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --
no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-
mix/setup/webpack.config.js
/var/www/html/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js:6
let mix = require('../src/index');
^^^
SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at requireConfig (/var/www/html/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:97:18)
at /var/www/html/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:104:17
at Array.forEach (native)

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-87-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "production"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! @ production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production 
node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ production script 'cross-env 
NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm 
installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     cross-env NODE_ENV=production         node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --    config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this     project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs 
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/html/npm-debug.log
```

How to issue this problem?

Comment: Check https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/264

Comment: @SérgioReis Hi, You can get more tips?

Comment: pretty much you need to upgrade node i guess

Answer (score 1):

I just followed those steps, and everything worked correctly. Try doing a full reset:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your `npm` and `node` versions to their latest first.

Just run `npm i -g npm`

And you do not need `sudo` for running `npm` scripts. Just use `npm run production`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using old/new version of node, which is not compatible with some of your packages (see for all the warnings when you run `npm install`). Try to change node version.

```sh
nvm use 14
```

Answer (score 0):

Node version make trouble in certain case, try
`n 14` to change node version to 14 if you have n installed